# How to read the secrets passed with github actions in NEXT js?

Tags: github-actions

I have configured my github actions `yml` as shown below:

```
name: GZB Unit Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  frontend_unit_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.1
      - name: Install Yarn
        run: |
          yarn
      - name: Run Unit Tests in CI
        run: |
          yarn test:ci
      - name: Build the Project
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_API_KEY }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_APP_ID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID }}
          FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL }}
          FB_ADMIN_RTDB_URL: ${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_RTDB_URL }}
          NODE_ENV: ${{ secrets.NODE_ENV }}
        run: |
          yarn build
```

Now when I try to access it via: `process.env.<VARIABLE_NAME>` it says undefined. Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong? The build process is failing, should I configure it some other way? I have added all these secrets in the secrets tab of github settings.

Comment: What is the config of your application ? Are you using Dotenv ?

Comment: Where do you access the env variables? Are you sure you need them during the build? Also, please focus on one secret only rather than pasting everything -- that makes it a bit easier to narrow down potential issues.

Answer (score 2):

NEXT uses its own web config to read files from `.env.local`. I was able to achieve my use case by creating a file `.env.local` and then passing in the secrets as shown below:

```
name: GZB Unit Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  frontend_unit_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.1
      - name: Install Yarn
        run: |
          yarn
      - name: Run Unit Tests in CI
        run: |
          yarn test:ci
      - name: Build the Project
        run: |
          touch .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_API_KEY=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_API_KEY }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_STORAGE_BUCKET }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_APP_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_APP_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY=${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY }} >> .env.local
          echo FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL=${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL }} >> .env.local
          echo FB_ADMIN_RTDB_URL=${{ secrets.FB_ADMIN_RTDB_URL }} >> .env.local
          echo NODE_ENV=${{ secrets.NODE_ENV }} >> .env.local
          yarn build
```

Comment: Do you think this would also work if I simply create .env.production?

Comment: didn't try but it should. However ensure that how next would pick variables in different places that is when local serving vs serving after yarn build

Comment: This answer saved me from hrs of troubleshooting.